# How to catch and store second bolded text into the database?

Tags: php, mysql

Supposed to store the whole string into the database with the sentence splitted up and the options and answers stored into its own columns.

> $example = 'She went to the store to (**buy**,buys,bought,buying) some snacks when she (sees,see,**saw**,look) the accident.';

Managed to store the whole string into the database and store them into respective columns and able to catch and store the first bolded text into database.

But unable to catch and store the second bolded text into its column in the database.

```
<?php 
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_NAME', 'palmdatas'); 
define('DB_USER','root');
define('DB_PASSWORD',''); 

$con=mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
$db=mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$con) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error()); 
$mode = $_POST['mode']; 
$question = $_POST['editor1']; 
$text = $question;

echo "\n";

$text = strip_tags($text);


function multiexplode ($delimiters,$string) {

$ready = str_replace($delimiters, $delimiters[0], $string);
$launch = explode($delimiters[0], $ready);
return  $launch;
}

$exploded = multiexplode(array(",","(",")"),$text);
 $question = $_POST['editor1']; 

 $answer1 = extractString($question, '<strong>', '</strong>');

$sql="INSERT INTO strucquestions (part1,op1,op2,op3,op4,ans1,part2,op1a,op2a,op3a,op4a,ans2,part3,mode) VALUES ('$exploded[0]','$exploded[1]','$exploded[2]','$exploded[3]','$exploded[4]','$answer1','$exploded[5]','$exploded[6]','$exploded[7]','$exploded[8]','$exploded[9]','$answer2','$exploded[10]','$mode')";

echo "Successfully Inserted!";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$result) {
 die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

function extractString($question, $start, $end) {
$question = " ".$question;
$ini = strpos($question, $start);
if ($ini == 0) return "";
$ini += strlen($start);
$len = strpos($question, $end, $ini) - $ini;
return substr($question, $ini, $len);

echo "close";
        mysql_close($con);      

} 
?>
<button onclick="window.location.href='insertion.php'">Next</button><br>        <br>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php:

> Searches subject for all matches to the regular expression given in pattern and puts them in matches in the order specified by flags.

That's probably more elegant than using the `strpos` business, for when using this you would have to loop until you've reached the end of your input string.